# Access parent binding context from dataTemplate resource (x:Reference)

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, controltemplate

I got a page in which I load multiple control template considering some business logic binded to a property in my viewModel.

```
<ContentView x:Name="ContentView"  ControlTemplate="{Binding ItemControlTemplate}">
</ContentView>
```

Inside this control template I got a CarouselViewControl which uses a DataTemplate.

```
<carousel:CarouselViewControl x:Name="CarouselViewMapTemplate" Position=" 
    {TemplateBinding BindingContext.CarouselPosition}" 
    PositionSelectedCommand="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.PositionChanged}" 
    Orientation="Horizontal" AnimateTransition="True" IsSwipeEnabled="False" 
    ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.Items}" InterPageSpacing="10" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsDataTemplate }">
</carousel:CarouselViewControl>
```

And inside this DataTemplate I would like to bind to a property in the ViewModel, which is also a DataTemplate.

```
 <maps:SfMaps  x:Name="sfmap" EnablePanning="False" EnableZooming="False" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <maps:SfMaps.Layers>
                <maps:ShapeFileLayer x:Name="ShapeLayer" Uri="FRA_adm0.shp" MarkerTemplate="{Binding Parent.BindingContext.MarkerDataTemplate}">

                </maps:ShapeFileLayer>
            </maps:SfMaps.Layers>
        </maps:SfMaps>
```

How can I achieve that ? I just tried

> {Binding Parent.BindingContext.MyProperty}

but this is not working. I also digged with Source property of binding, **but that won't do it as I don't have reference in my DataTemplate, used as resource in the app level ResourceDictionary.**

This DOESNT work ofc it does not find carouselView in the ResourceDictionary :

```
"{Binding Path=BindingContext.DisplayMarkerTemplateCommand, Source={x:Reference carouselView}}"
```

Not being able to do that breaks the whole point of having ResourceDictionary and clean templating if binding is not working from it with XAML.

THANKS !

Comment: Have you found the answer ?

Comment: Hello @trixo . unfortunately no ... I ended up by putting my data template in my page and using x:Reference. I still keep this open as I would really like it to be possible to avoid duplicate my data template in every pages. UpVote if you're interessted maybe one day a solution will be found.

Comment: What I did is that I have a controlled template defined in app.xaml and I have created binding class inside app.xaml.cs which holds all the binding properites I need in my app. Then i use contentpresenter inside which i render different views. I can access properties from app.xaml.cs inside my main.xaml(rendered to contentpresenter) simply by "{Binding VitalsData.PulseVisibility}". Maybe it will help ya

Comment: That's what I thought. Prob is I want to bind to view models property ... have you tested the performance ? I'm hesitating on your solution as I would create a ParentContext property that holds an entire view model on my app.xaml.cs ... Hmm I'll give it a shot. Thank you

Comment: Havent tested performance, but it feels smooth. My app is very simple tho.

Comment: app.xaml is kept in the memory all the time not disposed. thats a bad implementation in my opinion.